# Disable zsh prezto "completion" module autocorrect

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm using prezto with zsh and its "completion" module has some autocorrect stuff which I don't want. I just want the autocomplete and menu highlights, but no autocorrection (which is dangerous and should be forbidden by law! :P )

For example, I have the following directories:
src/project/
opensrc/library/

When I type "src/li", it changes to "opensrc/li". I don't want that, or at least no automatically (a y/n prompt would be nice).

Is there any way to disable it without disabling the completion module completely, or have it prompt (y/n)?

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have found the solution. Add the following lines to the .zshrc file, and it should stop the autocorrection:

```
unsetopt correct
unsetopt correctall
DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"
```

Comment: In my tests, just `unsetopt correct` was enough to disable prompt like `zsh: correct 'golan' to 'goland' [nyae]?`.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking the 'completion' module in github you will find this notice:

> This projects aims at gathering/developing new completion scripts that
>   are not available in Zsh yet. The scripts are meant to be contributed
>   to the Zsh project when stable enough.

This module is not stable enough. Just disable it in `~/.zpreztorc`.

You will still get basic, Bash-style tab completion in zsh.